# Htaccess won't work with ajax/php

Tags: htaccess, ajax

Sending ajax request by jquery doesn't working with htaccess. Works without htaccess.

`product_configurator.php` -> `fetch_data_p.php`

```
$.ajax({
            url:"fetch_data_p.php",
            method:"POST",
```

htaccess `RewriteRule ^(product_configurator)\.html/(\d+)&(\d+)$ $1.php?prometheus_id=$2&id=$3 [L]`

1. it works
   http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/photo_gallery/public/product_configurator.html?prometheus_id=10082&id=30
2. did not work
   http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/photo_gallery/public/product_configurator.html/10082&30

Why is this happening?

@MrWhite **SOULUTION**

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost/photo_gallery/public/fetch_data_p.php",
    method:"POST",
```

Comment: Why do you want to rewrite your AJAX URLs like this?   It isn't standard practice to do so.  AJAX calls are usually easier to make with query parameters.  The URLs don't need to be "clean" for SEO.

Comment: @Stephen I wanted to add at the end rewrite map category and product name `/cotton&cotton-produkt`. I don't know if it's good practice to use ajax with htaccess. Is it possible at all.

Comment: The not working should have nothing to do with AJAX.  It isn't common to try to rewrite the `PATH_INFO` to `QUERY_STRING` within the same script.  I'm not sure if it would solve your problem but have you tried rewriting a different URL like `/photo_gallery/public/p/10082&30` to `/photo_gallery/public/product_configurator.html?prometheus_id=10082&id=30`?

Comment: @Stephen Added `RewriteRule ^(product_configurator)\.html/p/(\d+)&(\d+)$ $1.php?prometheus_id=$2&id=$3 [L]` same no answer

Comment: How about a rule like `RewriteRule ^photo_gallery/public/p/(\d+)&(\d+)$ photo_gallery/public/product_configurator\.html\.php?prometheus_id=$1&id=$2` that doesn't have path conflicts in it?

Comment: Also, which .htaccess file are you putting this in?   Are you putting it in the document root, in the `photo_gallery` directory, or in the `photo_gallery/public` directory?

Comment: @ Stephen Ostermiller photo_gallery/public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem would seem to be that you are using a *relative* client-side URL to make the AJAX request and since you are using a URL at a different path depth `fetch_data_p.php` is not found.

The AJAX request for `fetch_data_p.php` is relative to the visible URL in the browser. You need to make this URL root-relative (starting with a slash). eg. `/photo_gallery/public/fetch_data_p.php`.

Currently:

When at the URL `/photo_gallery/public/product_configurator.html?prometheus_id=10082&id=30`, your AJAX call to `fetch_data_p.php` resolves to `/photo_gallery/public/fetch_data_p.php` and it works.

However, when at the URL `/photo_gallery/public/product_configurator.html/10082&30`, your AJAX call to `fetch_data_p.php` resolves to `/photo_gallery/public/product_configurator.html/fetch_data_p.php` which naturally fails - 404 Not Found.

This doesn't really have anything to do with the URL rewrite itself in `.htaccess`, except for the fact the client-side URL is different and importantly, a different path depth. The AJAX call itself is not being rewritten.

Comment: Every time you write back to me, it enlightens me and everything becomes clear:) `url:"http://localhost/photo_gallery/public/fetch_data_p.php",`